# Do native (non-$scope, etc) members of angularjs controller objects do anything?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Learning **angularjs**, the curve is steep but I can see that it's going somewhere.

Given the following:

```
var app = angular.module('theApp',[]);

app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
    var self=this;
    $scope.thing = "hi.";
    this.thang = "yo.";
    $scope.doIt=function(){
        return self.thang;
    };
});
```

`thing` and `doIt()` are exposed through **$scope**, but `thang` is not:

```
<body ng-app="theApp">
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
    <div>{{thing}}</div>
    <div>{{thang}}</div>
    <div>{{doIt()}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there any way to bind or otherwise expose `thang`? Or is `this.` completely pointless inside an **ngController**?

No problem if it is, just trying to get it straight in my head. I'm getting the idea that and **ngController** only communicates through **$scope** (and other ng service objects), they aren't independently accessible to other code; and I see that as a basically good thing, within **anjularjs**.

But it means you have to go all-in with **angularjs**; legacy/external code has to be wrapped in **angularjs** services and stuff in order to communicate across an **ngController**, would that be a fair statement?

I'm using angularjs 1.2.13, does the behavior change across versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-controller` tag can put the controller on the scope. These are equivalent:

```
<body ng-app="theApp">
<div ng-controller="Controller1 as c">
    <div>{{thing}}</div>
    <div>{{c.thang}}</div>
    <div>{{doIt()}}</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And:

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {
    var self=this;
    $scope.thing = "hi.";
    $scope.c = this;
    this.thang = "yo.";
    $scope.doIt=function(){
        return self.thang;
    };
});
```

Personally I think putting the name in the tag usually makes more sense as the template reads better.

Remember you can also access controllers which aren't on `$scope` from the `link` function of a directive. When you do that you refer to the name you gave the controller when you registered it, `Controller1` in this case. See the `require` attribute here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: d'oh! makes perfect sense now that i see it, thank you for zooming it in for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to bind or otherwise expose thang?

It depends how you want it to be exposed.  If you want it to be available in the view; you'll have to put it into the $scope.

If you want to share the value with other controllers, you'll probably want to use a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.understanding_services) or to store the value.

> Or is this. completely pointless inside an ngController?

I consider variables, or methods, not in the $scope to be similar to a protected variable [or method].  Depending what your building their can be uses for that.  I would not consider it pointless.

> But it means you have to go all-in with angularjs; legacy/external
>   code has to be wrapped in angularjs services and stuff in order to
>   communicate across an ngController, would that be a fair statement?

No, it doesn't mean that.  For example, I once wrote an app with a login form, and needed to hash the password before calling a remote service.  I just Googled and found a JAvaScript hash library; then imported it into the html page (AKA Used the script tag), and was able to access the hash function from within the controller without doing any other work.  This is due to the nature of JavaScript and how browsers work.

However, by doing this I added an external dependency into my controller which would make it difficult to write tests against.  If I had wrapped the library in an Angular service, then passed it into the controller I would have built a semi-self-documenting API for the controller that could be tested with known dependencies.

So, you don't have to wrap external services in AngularJS.  But, you may want to.  As long as you understand the trade offs your making, you can make good decisions for your use case. (Just like any 'best practice').

> I'm using angularjs 1.2.13, does the behavior change across versions?

All versions of Angular I've used have the same "Controller / Scope / Dependency Injection" approach.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate these insights.